# iPhone - Login screen as modal iOS > 5.0

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

For some reason presenting a view controller modally after ios 5.0 before the presenters view appears no longer works if you do this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    LoginController *loginController = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:loginController animated:NO];
}
```

If you try `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` it does not work either, as it it is too soon to present anything. Previous to ios 5.0 this worked fine, now the login controller is presented but before that for about 0.3 seconds you can see the presenter view.

How can you present the login screen modally, without showing the uiviewcontroller.view presenting the login screen?.

Comment: did you try setting `[self presentModalViewController:loginController animated:NO];` before `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`? I suppose that in this case you will get that loginController before seeing anything of the main view(or whatever its called)

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if @Novarg's idea works.

Comment: @Novarg yes I tried that, but I get the same results unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not saying this is good, but what I end up doing is adding a `UIImageView` that matches the Xcode screen image/splash screen in the main controller's view in `viewWillAppear`. Then I can modally present the other controller and it looks like it's appearing over the splash screen. Then in the main controller's `viewDidDisappear`, I just remove the splash screen from the view.

Not elegant. But it does make it easy to animate the transitions from the splash screen to the first controller, which I like.